# Cannot GET while using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

my router.js

```js
const express = require("express")
const Note = require("../models/nodeModel")
const router = express.Router()

router.route("/notes").get((req, res) => {
    Note.find({ show_day: "2020-9-10" })
        .then(foundNotes => res.json(foundNotes))
})

module.exports = router
```

my server.js

```js
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const cors = require("cors")
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/my-app")

app.use("/",require("./routes/noteRouter"))

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("server is running on port 3000");
})
```

my nodeModel.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const noteSchema = {
    show_day:String,
    diary_day: String,
    content: String
}

const Note = mongoose.model("diary",noteSchema)

module.exports = Note;
```

When I try to console.log Note.find(), it works. But when I run server.js, browser says Cannot GET/
Why it can't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have `/notes` endpoint, there's no `/` route.

You should change route in router.js like this:

```
const express = require("express")
const Note = require("../models/nodeModel")
const router = express.Router()

router.route("/").get((req, res) => {
    Note.find({ show_day: "2020-9-10" })
        .then(foundNotes => res.json(foundNotes))
})

module.exports = router
```

or access `/notes` instead of `/`.

Comment: Great! Would you mind to mark my answer as correct then? :)